# error in or clause mongodb while using in pycharm

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm

i am using mongodb in my project so that i want to save and retrieve data from it, but when i use $or in it pycharm is showing error (underlined by red colour) at $or and saying statement expected, found OR_keyword
while using the same in mongo shell i am able to get the result, so plz help me my code is as below

```
import bottle
import pymongo


class GuestbookDAO(object):
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.db = database
        self.details = database.details

    def find_names(self):
        full_detail = []
        for each_detail in self.details.find():
            full_detail.append({'baseurl': each_detail['baseurl'], 'campaignsource': each_detail['campaignsource'],
                                'campaignmedium': each_detail['campaignmedium'], 'campaignterm': each_detail['campaignterm'],
                                'campaigncontent': each_detail['campaigncontent'], 'campaignname': each_detail['campaignname']})
        return full_detail

    def insert_details(self, baseurl, campaignsource, campaignmedium, campaignterm, campaigncontent, campaignname):
        newname = {'baseurl': baseurl, 'campaignsource': campaignsource, 'campaignmedium': campaignmedium,
                   'campaignterm': campaignterm, 'campaigncontent': campaigncontent, 'campaignname': campaignname}
        self.details.insert(newname)

    def search(self, string):
        full_details = []
        for detail in self.details.find({ $or: [{'baseurl': string}, {'campaignsource': string},
                                                 {'campaignmedium': string}, {'campaignterm': string},
                                                 {'campaigncontent': string}, {'campaignname': string}]}):
        full_details.append({'baseurl': detail['baseurl'], 'campaignsource': detail['campaignsource'],
                             'campaignmedium': detail['campaignmedium'], 'campaignterm': detail['campaignterm'],
                             'campaigncontent': detail['campaigncontent'], 'campaignname': detail['campaignname']})
        return full_details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo shell uses javascript, but in pycharm you are working on python.

Javascript accepts object string keys which are not in quotes, python does not.

Valid in Javascript:

```
{$or:{a:1}}
```

To make it valid in python, all object keys must be in quotes :

```
 {"$or":{ "a":1}}
```